# Python programming: multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, nltk, wordnet

I have a script. It's CPU-intensive and I have access to a multi-core machine, but it's not showing its utilization. How to use the multiprocessing library in Python 3? Or maybe something else?  Any suggestions how to modify the script are welcome. Thank you!

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

from itertools import chain 

for line in infile:

  word = line.strip()

  if (word not in Dict):

      Dict[word]=(set(["-","-","-"]),0)

  lemma = lmtzr.lemmatize(word)

  for w, net1, net2, lch in syn(lemma):



      if (word not in Dict):

          Dict[word]={}

      for l in net2.lemmas():

          synonyms.append(l.name())


  Dict[word] = (set(synonyms),round(lch,2))


  synonyms =[]



infile.close()


csv_writer(Dict, "Text8_types_similar_lch.csv")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use joblib. First, put your code in a function that works on any number of lines. You can either write the results of the function to a csv file, resulting in a different file for each process, which you will have to merge, or just return something:

```
def my_func(lines):
    return_dict = {}
    for line in lines:
        # put your code here
    return return_dict
```

Then, write a function to split up `lines` into chunks of some smaller size:

```
from itertools import islice

def grouper(n, iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        chunk = tuple(islice(it, n))
       if not chunk:
           return
       yield chunk
```

Finally, call joblib's `Parallel` to pass each chunk of data to your function:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

results = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(
    delayed(my_func)(line_chunk) for line_chunk in grouper(lines, 500))
```

`results` will then be a list of returned items from `my_func`, and you can merge them how you like.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed suggestions. Could you please clarify how to use the results with my_func?

Comment: If each call to your function writes to a different CSV file, there's no reason to return anything. But the main script can also take the results and write them to CSV.

Comment: Yea, you can either write to a file from each function call, or once you have a list of dicts, you can combine them. It really depends on you use case. You can write your own code to merge the dictionaries. I also have some code that allows you to merge dicts with custom logic: https://github.com/Lguyogiro/BetterDict

Comment: I should pass my_func(line_chunk) to delayed(), right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've updated my example code. You pass your function to 'delayed' and call the result, passing the arguments.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! It runs on my toy data, but it doesn't seem to make things faster?

Comment: It won't be faster on small datasets, because there is a lot of overhead to pickle everything and send it off to each core. You will notice the difference when the total dataset, as well as each 'chunk', is large.